# Apache Proxy balancerMember with query string parameter

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, apache2

I'm working on with apache proxy, I want to use Proxy balancer member with query string value, but it's not worked I expected.

Here's my configuration.

```
Listen 49154 
<VirtualHost *:49154> 
         <Proxy balancer://vncServer> 
                BalancerMember ws://server1 route=1 retry=1 
                BalancerMember ws://server2 route=2 retry=1 
                BalancerMember ws://server3 route=3 retry=1 
                ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID 
        </Proxy> 

        RewriteEngine on 
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} port=(.*) 

        #to make ws://server1:(port value from query string)/websockify
        RewriteRule (.*) balancer://vncServer:%1/websockify [P]
        ProxyPassReverse (.*) balancer://vncServer:%1/websockify 
</VirtualHost>
```

but I checked in log that, always connect with 80 port.

works fine without balancer like

```
Listen 49154 
<VirtualHost *:49154> 

        RewriteEngine on 
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} port=(.*) 
        RewriteRule (.*) ws://server1:%1/websockify [P]
        ProxyPassReverse (.*) ws://server1:%1/websockify 

</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way to connect with balancer memeber with query string ports value?
Any help will be thankful.